# CRUD Application in API using Postman

Tags: laravel, api, postman

So i have a **crud application** for `cliets`. I have made it with Laravel, and now i want to make the crud in the **ApiController** and only make it work with **Postman**.

When i use POST, error: `Creating default object from empty value` (at the $client->clt_name)

When i use GET, it just says Validation error in the `message`

**This is the API**

```
public function clients(Request $request){

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name'          =>  'regex:/^[^{}<>]+$/u|max:255|required',
        'adress'         => 'regex:/[A-Za-z0-9\-\\,.]+/'
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        $message = "Please fill in the right information";
        return $this->sendError('Validation Error.' . $message);        
    }

    $client_id = $request->clt_id;

    $client->clt_name = $request->name; 
    $client->clt_adres = $request->adress;
    $client->save();


    $client = client::where('clt_id', $client_id)->first();
    if($client){
        if(!is_null($client)){
            return $this->sendError("404", 'client not found');
        }
    }
    else{
        //new client
        $client = new client; 
    }         
}
```

**And the Delete function:**

```
public function delete_client(Request $request){
        $client = client::find($id);
        $client->delete();    
    }
```

I'm pretty new to making an API, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do in clients function?. And from where you getting $id in delete_client function?

Comment: in the clients function i'm trying to make it that if there is no `$id` found, it makes a new form, otherwise it goes to the edit. And i dont know how to get the `id` from the clients in the delete.

Comment: can you post the routes and form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
public function clients(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name'          =>  'regex:/^[^{}<>]+$/u|max:255|required',
        'adress'         => 'regex:/[A-Za-z0-9\-\\,.]+/'
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        $message = "Please fill in the right information";
        return $this->sendError('Validation Error.' . $message);        
    }

    $client_id = $request->clt_id;
    $clt_name = $request->name; 
    $clt_adres = $request->adress;

    return client::updateOrCreate(
        ['clt_id' => $client_id],
        ['clt_name' => $clt_name, 'clt_adres' => $clt_adres]
    );     
}
```

This will create new client if no clt_id exists, else it will update the client.

Comment: Thank you! The delete function however can't find the client. not sure why. I used this: `$klant_id = $request->input('klt_id');
        $klant = Klant::where('klt_id', $klant_id)->first();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

create an object and assign values

```
 $client= new Client;  //your table name
 $client->clt_name = $request->name; 
 $client->clt_adres = $request->adress;
 $client->save();
```

Comment: FYI : Client is not table name it's model name, laravel just assumes the table name (plural of model name) in case it's not overwriten in your model

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
public function clients(Request $request){

  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name'          =>  'regex:/^[^{}<>]+$/u|max:255|required',
    'adress'         => 'regex:/[A-Za-z0-9\-\\,.]+/'
  ]);

  if($validator->fails()){
    $message = "Please fill in the right information";
    return $this->sendError('Validation Error.' . $message);        
  }

  $client = client::where('clt_id', $request->clt_id)->first();

  if($client !== null){
    // update client - all fields must be fillable in client model
    $client = $client->update($request->except('clt_id'));
  } else{
    //new client - all fields must be fillable in client model
    $client = Client::create($request->all());
  }

  return response()->json($client);
}
```

Comment: Tried your code, and added keys and values in postman, but it now says nothing. just blank unfortunately